# Add new column in user-database with controller of lecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

i have a little system with some users.
An user with admin-rights can create a new lecture.
Thats already working.

Now i want to solve the problem that users can sign up to lectures.
So i want to add a new column (boolean type) e.g. to lecture1 in my users database when i create a new lecture. So i can set the variable to true if an user sign up.

Is that a good idea or would it be better to have a database (e.g. signupstatus) with an exercise_id, an user_id. When there is an entry the user has already sign up to the lecture.

Or does anyone have an better idea?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is always better. You will never want to create such columns(`lecture1`...) in `User` table, for each new lecture which to added in your system. Imagine the series of such columns [`lecture1`,`lecture2`,`lecture3`,`lecturen`...] => **Totally unconventional** and against the design principles.

What you want is a simple **Many-to-Many** relationship. A `Lecture` can be enrolled by many `users`; a `User` can subscribe to many `lectures`.

You should follow [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) to achieve it.
This will create a table - `lectures_users` and store `lecture_id` and `user_id` to maintain the relationship

Comment: Thank you! Sounds right. I'll try it in this way.